# Rejecting a the returned promise inside a then block

Tags: swift, generics, promisekit

Say I have two promises I want to combine with a `when(resolved:)`. I want to reject the promise if there was a problem with the first promise, but resolve otherwise. Essentially, this is what I want to do:

```
func personAndPetPromise() -> Promise<(Person, Pet?)> {
    let personPromise: Promise<Person> = ...
    let petPromise: Promise<Pet> = ...

    when(resolved: personPromise, petPromise).then { _ -> (Person, Pet?) in
        if let error = personPromise.error {
            return Promise(error: error) // syntax error
        }
        guard let person = personPromise.value else {
            return Promise(error: myError) // syntax error
        }
        return (person, petPromise.value)
    }
}
```

such that externally I can do something like this:

```
personAndPetPromise().then { person, pet in
    doSomethingWith(person, pet)
}.catch { error in
    showError(error)
}
```

The problem lies within the the `then { _ in` block in `personAndPetPromise`. There's no way that method can return both a `Promise(error:)` and a `(Person, Pet?)`.

How else can I reject the block?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are two overloads of the `then` function:

```
public func then<U>(on q: DispatchQueue = .default, execute body: @escaping (T) throws -> U) -> Promise<U>
public func then<U>(on q: DispatchQueue = .default, execute body: @escaping (T) throws -> Promise<U>) -> Promise<U>
```

The first one's `body` returns a `U` and causes `then` to return `Promise<U>`.

The second one's `body` returns a `Promise<U>` and causes `then` to return `Promise<U>`.

Since in this case we want to return an error or a valid response, we're forced to use the second overload.

Here's a working version. The main difference is I changed it from `-> (Person, Pet?)` to `-> Promise<(Person, Pet?)>`:

```
func personAndPetPromise() -> Promise<(Person, Pet?)> {
    let personPromise: Promise<Person> = ...
    let petPromise: Promise<Pet> = ...

    when(resolved: personPromise, petPromise).then { _ -> Promise<(Person, Pet?)> in
        if let error = personPromise.error {
            return Promise(error: error)
        }
        guard let person = personPromise.value else {
            return Promise(error: myError)
        }
        return Promise(value: (person, petPromise.value))
    }
}
```

Another way to do the same thing is by **throwing the error** rather than attempting to return it:

```
func personAndPetPromise() -> Promise<(Person, Pet?)> {
    let personPromise: Promise<Person> = ...
    let petPromise: Promise<Pet> = ...

    when(resolved: personPromise, petPromise).then { _ -> (Person, Pet?) in
        if let error = personPromise.error {
            throw error
        }
        guard let person = personPromise.value else {
            throw myError
        }
        return (person, petPromise.value)
    }
}
```